# Появляется горизонтальный скролл на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html5, css3, вёрстка

Сел писать адаптивную верстку, пока только на одной из страниц сайта оно работает как надо, например в chrome в режиме просмотра кода iphone 5 все элементы 320px в ширину, некоторые почему-то хотят быть 330px в ширину когда им задаёшь width=100%, приходится использовать хак

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

в общем, для мобильных устройств в хроме виден горизонтальный скролл, словно от контейнера  идёт отступ справа в 10px.

Притом все элементы показывают ширину 320px как положено.

На самом например физическом iphone 5 видно что этот отступ порядка 30-50px.

Может кто-то опытный в верстке посмотреть, что это может такое быть, что вызывает такой отступ?
Страница для тестов:

protasov.by/contacts

Comment: Вопросу уже больше двух лет, а сайт все еще с горизонтальной прокруткой. Вообщем проблема в блоке ".dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"

Answer (score 1):

У вас и не на мобильном браузере такая проблема. Смотрю в Safari на Mac. Некогда разбираться в этой кривой версте, выкладываю хотфикс:

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```